# Syntax error is an Error or Exception?

Tags: java

Syntax error in java comes under Exceptions or Errors??

As far as i know errors are something that is irrecoverable by programmer but syntax errors are recoverable at programmer level.

And after any syntax error while compiling you get this meassage-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

Thank you

Comment: Syntax error is a compilation error, so it has nothing to do with exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

Syntax error is neither an Error nor an Exception because both of them happen during runtime, and syntax error causes a compilation error which would prevent the program from compiling and therefore from running.

Comment: Don't compilation errors prevent the program from *compiling* in the first place?

Comment: @npinti that is true and petty.

Comment: @Amnon:But when you compile with syntax error you get a message of exception--Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

Comment: @Stone that might happen when you compile the code with the syntax error in an IDE such as Eclipse.